# Passing graph into HTML page using Flask

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask, graph

I am generating a graph with help of data which is stored in a `static` folder of the flask application. The image is saved using `plt.savefig()`. Afterward, I want to display that image in an HTML page.

Till this graph is shown in output but when I regenerate the graph by with parameters it is stored into `static` folder but its output shows an older graph which was first generated.

app.py

```
@app.route('/historic_graph_search')
def historic_graph_search():
    fig = df[[attribute]].plot()
    file_path = "static/images/mytable1.png"
    data = plt.savefig(file_path)
    return render_template("historic_graph_search.html", fig=fig)
```

historic_graph_search.html

```
<img src="../static/images/mytable1.png">
 {{ fig }}
```

I need to give graph as output in an HTML page each time `historic_graph_search()` is called.

Comment: Is it the case of getting an older unrefreshed version of `mytable1.png` on front-end? Or the `fig` data value is older?